# 2nd Order ODE w/ Periodic BCs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am a bit rusty with ODEs and would appreciate some help with the following. I am trying to solve a linear homogeneous PDE with separation of variables. The time component was easy enough. It was an exponential of the form $G(t)=c \exp(-\lambda b t)$ where $c$ and $b$ are positive constants and $\lambda$ is the separation constant (eigenvalue).

The PDE is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} &= \nu \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial x^2}\\
u(0,t) &= u(L,t) \quad , \quad \frac{du(0,t)}{dx} = \frac{du(L,t)}{dx}\\
u(x,0) &= u_o(x)
\end{align}
$$

Now I want to solve the following 2nd order homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients for the space component $\phi(x)$, with periodic boundary conditions.

$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2} - b \frac{d\phi}{dx} + \lambda \phi= 0 \\
\phi(0) = \phi(L) \quad , \quad \frac{d\phi}{dx}\Bigg|_0 = \frac{d\phi}{dx}\Bigg|_L
$$

I know that I want $\lambda$ to be positive so that $G(t)$ decays with time. If I assume a solution for $\phi(x)$ of the form $\exp(rx)$ then I get the characteristic equation

$$
r = \frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4\lambda}}{2}
$$

I know that I want $\lambda$ to be positive but I don't know whether it is greater than, equal, or less than $b^2$ - I don't know $\lambda$. Okay. I will assume at first that it is greater than $b^2$ which means the characteristic equation has complex roots. In that case I know the solution will have the following form.

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac{-b}{2}\\
\beta &= \frac{\sqrt{4\lambda-b^2}}{2}\\
\phi(x) &= \exp(\alpha x)( C_1 \cos\beta x + C_2\sin\beta x)
\end{align}
$$

Assuming I'm correct up to this point, this is where I get a little confused. I need to find $C_1$, $C_2$, and $\lambda$. I think I should be able to use the following two equations to determine $C_1$ and $C_2$, right? (two equations, two unknowns)

$$
\phi(0) = \phi(L) \quad , \quad \frac{d\phi}{dx}\Bigg|_0 = \frac{d\phi}{dx}\Bigg|_L
$$

But I am still left with $\lambda$. Do I have to infer it's form based on the results for $C_1$ and $C_2$? Pick something so that $C_1$ or $C_2$ do not result in the trivial solution?

Comment: It should be $\alpha=\frac{b}{2}$... as you have negative damping ($b>0$) your solution will explode as $x\to \infty$. Also, you should have countably many possible values of $\lambda$ and the solutions form your Fourier series, and presumably one of your constants will be arbitrary. You should state the original PDE with bcs to get better help.

Comment: @epiliam I added the original PDE

Comment: Are $v$ and $\nu$ constants?

Comment: @epiliam Yes - It is a linear PDE with constant coefficients.

Comment: I don't understand how your BCs for your ODE came from your BCs for the PDE. Your derivative condition for the ODE is not seen in the PDE. Are there missing BCs? As it stands the PDE problem is not well formed. Also, are $v, \nu$ positive? That would surprise me... it seems unphysical

Comment: So the ODEs came from looking for a solution of the form $u(x,t)=\phi(x)G(t)$. I did not restate the derivative condition because I was being lazy, but it still applies. $v$ and $\nu$ are both positive constants.

Comment: I know where your ODEs come from. I am interested in the BCs. So are you saying in the original PDE you have the condition $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(0, t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(L, t)$?

Comment: @epiliam Yes - I apologize for being unclear.